# App crashes after adding Realm framework in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, realm

I had added Realm.framework to my project by following [How to add the parent path to RealmSwift.framework in the “Framework Search Paths” section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896667/how-to-add-the-parent-path-to-realmswift-framework-in-the-framework-search-path) link. Even though i had followed all the steps given in the above link, still my app crashes with error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
Referenced from: /Users/softence-one/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B602CE3A-BF0A-434F-96FF-BA749B4A7D70/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E8937185-3EBC-4314-A5E8-31CEF89A40A5/CityGuide.app/CityGuide
Reason: image not found
```

So please suggest me any link to install the realm.framework correctly in objective C. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by not adding the framework into the "Embedded Binaries" section of your project's settings. See these [instructions](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation) in Realm's docs for all the steps in the Objective-C installation.