# Swift unit testing with Realm and RAC

Tags: swift, unit-testing, realm, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to write some unit tests for my app. I am using Realm and RAC frameworks, but neither of them I can use in my unit tests.

```
import XCTest

@testable import FlightRecords

class RecordsViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

    var viewModelUnderTest: RecordsViewModel!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        viewModelUnderTest = RecordsViewModel()
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.inMemoryIdentifier = self.name
    }
}
```

In the code above, I get an error, but my app is working just normally with Realm (and RAC). The error is:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Realm'

I have tried different combinations for "Target Membership" and none of them worked. At this point, I have all frameworks' Target Membership for both app and tests.

Any advice?

Comment: try to `import RealmSwift`

Comment: That acually help along with this: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-unit-tests-or-a-framework
I had to link my frameworks (downloaded with carthage) to test's build phases and than import them to my unit tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add the parent path to RealmSwift.framework in the “Framework Search Paths” section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896667/how-to-add-the-parent-path-to-realmswift-framework-in-the-framework-search-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import RealmSwift` in your test cases, also you should add the parent path to `RealmSwift.framework` to your unit test’s "Framework Search Paths".

See also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#debugging