# My Framework is Compiling to an Unexpected Build Products Directory

Tags: ios, frameworks, realm, bundle, xcode9

I have a project named 'MyProject'.  I added a framework to the project named 'MyFramework'.  I use the Realm cocoapod within MyFramework.  I linked Realm.framework to MyFramework under the General tab.  I also copied the Realm.framework to the MyFramework bundle under the 'Copy Bundle Resources' tab.

When I try to build MyProject I receive the error: "error: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-abc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm.framework: No such file or directory".

When I check the 'MyProject.abc' directory I see the Realm.Framework saved at 'Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm/Realm.framework' folder and not 'Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm.framework' as expected in the error.  Any suggestions?   FYI, a command named 'CpResource' is being executed which leads to the error.  I'm not sure how to set where 'CpResource' looks for the Realm.framework.

Comment: Update: I received this error when performing 'pod install' -> [!] The `MyProject [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.debug.xcconfig'.     - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.    I fixed this error by following [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570233/whats-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries-with-cocoapods-swift-3-and-xcode].  I'm still having the problem above.

Comment: I think I may be close to figuring out the issue.  Based on this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896667/how-to-add-the-parent-path-to-realmswift-framework-in-the-framework-search-path] I need to set the Framework Search Path.  Presently, the search path includes 'build/Debug-iphoneos/Realm'.  However, Realm.framework is located in the 'Build/Products/Debug-**iphonesimulator**/Realm' folder.  Again, any help would be appreciated.